# How to make Jmeter to make the same request twice

Tags: jmeter

I encountered a problem in Jmeter.
I have a scenario that I need to check, and it is to send the exactly the same http requests multiple times.
the request will not get any answer.
the problem is that Jmeter do it only once, it not even try to perform it in the second time.
I put it in a loop and still only once, 
is their any solution? how can I make jmeter to perform multiple http requests.
for manual solution I use postman and send the same requests over and over again manually. 
Is their any solution?  I put the test plan, junk 1 + 2 + 3 are just the same call without any change, and the response is just 200, why Jmeter not run the http more than once?

[[image]][test plan junk 2 + 3 not do]

[[image]][loop controller set to forever]

[[image]][all the junks are the same]

[[image]][response of junk is 200ok nothing more]

[[image]][no junk loop or 2 + 3 calls performed ]

[[image]][logs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came across this while debugging the same issue - our problem was the "Use Cache-Control" option was ticked under "HTTP Cache Manager". This stops subsequent GET requests being processed, without an obvious warning or message.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into red `1` near the yellow exclamation sign there is an error presumably connected with `junk2`, check out *jmeter.log* file for details, you should be able to identify the reason from there.

Also check your [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) settings, especially `Action to be taken after a Sampler error` parameter, if it is set to `Stop Test` or `Stop Test Now` might be a good explanation.

Normally people go for [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) in order to repeat certain step(s), it allows to define condition(s) to exit the loop.

Comment: Hey Dimitry, the thread  group is set to continue as what to do in error. this issue I can not resolved, nothing in logs. also if I will add any parameter to the url in call 2 and another in call 3 for example &dimitry&bastian  it will perform it. the problem is not in the sampler, and I tried also the while. still jmeter not performed duplicate requests if he is not getting response. is it use cache?   I am struggling with this issue for a long time

Comment: the problem is that the http calls are identical 100%. and the response is just 200ok without  anything else. if I change something in the requests it fires them as expected, since this issue I can not perform loops or load testing for this scenario, so manually people open postman and enter the url and press enter 100 times.

Comment: Added pic of logs, maybe it will help, no error in logs  only warn about     1. WARN o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Existing CacheManager HTTP Cache Manager superseded by HTTP Cache Manager. I do not know if Jmeter have cache or not, but the buttom line is that I need him to actually make the http call, No cache or anything since I need to summarized the duplication calls, and it can not be done.             CacheManager: Entry CacheEntry [lastModified=null, etag=null, expires=Fri May 17 16:13:32 IDT 2019, varyHeader=null] with no vary found for url

Comment: If JMeter doesn't receive response - it will not go further, you need to put something into `Timeouts` section which lives under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults)). HTTP is a stateful protocol and JMeter will wait for response prior to firing a new request.

Comment: still do not understand if I use the same url that not get answer, but first time with parameter &d and another sampler with &s, it is working, meaning not waiting, and perform the two sampler. but if I use &d in the first sampler and &d in the second sampler it will not performed the second sampler. in both sampler it will get the same response 200 ok with nothing in the page, so what is the difference? why if I change the url parameter it is working? (in both cases the same results for the same site) and the url param are just for fun. without use.

Comment: @Dimitry the problem is that Jmeter knows that the calls are identical and not even try to perform the second call. but if I fool Jmeter and add something to the url for example &blabla=bla it will make the second call. if what you are saying is correct why in this scenario Jmeter not wait for response? and just moved to the sampler with blabla